# Set email cookie in rails and find user according to the email cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Kind of new to rails and I'm in need of some help!

I'm using the devise gem and I'm trying to find the current user that just signed-up or that is trying to sign-in by setting up a `cookies[:email]`.

I have the following inside the sessions_contoller.rb and the registrations_contoller.rb

```
def create
  cookies[:email] = params[:user][:email]
  #and some other code as well
end

def destroy
  super
  cookies.delete :email
end
```

The following method is to find the user according to the email:

```
def current_client
  if cookies["email"].present?
    User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end
end
```

If I check from the browser I can see the email cookie is there, not sure how to check from the rails c though.

But the current_client method doesn't seem to be working.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

While setting the value of cookie, try to set it as below:

```
cookies[:email] = {:value => params[:user][:email], :domain => :your_domain, :expires => 30.days.from_now}
```

Also you can check the cookie by printing its value in controller to verify it was set or not.